# Can I Send Emails to Multiple Receivers using IEmailSender Interface in ASP.Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-core

I'm beginner to  ASP.Net core. Actually I'm using ASP.Net Core 3.0. I want to Send emails to Multiple Receivers. Can I use IEmailSender Interface? Or any suggetion?

My IEmailSender implementation is like,

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    private string host;
    private int port;
    private bool enableSSL;
    private string userName;
    private string password;

    public EmailSender(string host, int port, bool enableSSL, string userName, string password)
    {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.enableSSL = enableSSL;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
    {
        var client = new SmtpClient(host, port)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password),
            EnableSsl = enableSSL
        };
        return client.SendMailAsync(
            new MailMessage(userName, email, subject, htmlMessage) { IsBodyHtml = true }
        );
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The `To` Field of `MailMessage` is a collection. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to?view=netcore-3.0 You cann add mutliple MailAdresses to it.

Comment: How to pass MailMessage  collection to SendEmailAsync method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I do it in another way. Ill post it here and it will help for someone..

1. I create new interface called 'IExtendedEmailSender' inheriting the 'IEmailSender' interface.

   ```
    public interface IExtendedEmailSender : IEmailSender
    {

    }
   ```
2. Create new abstract method for send emails to multiple receivers.

   ```
   public interface IExtendedEmailSender : IEmailSender
   {
       Task SendBulkEmailAsync(string[] emails, string subject, string htmlMessage);
   }
   ```
3. create new method for check mail address.

   ```
   public static bool CheckIsValiedEmailAddress(string address)
   {
       try
       {
           var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(address);
           return addr.Address == address;
       }
       catch
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create new class calling 'EmailSender' and implement the 'IExtendedEmailSender' interface.

   ```
   public class EmailSender : IExtendedEmailSender
   {
       private string host;
       private int port;
       private bool enableSSL;
       private string userName;
       private string password;

       public EmailSender(string host, int port, bool enableSSL, string userName, 
       string password)
       {
           this.host = host;
           this.port = port;
           this.enableSSL = enableSSL;
           this.userName = userName;
           this.password = password;
       }


       public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
       {
           var client = new SmtpClient(host, port)
           {
               Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password),
               EnableSsl = enableSSL
           };
           return client.SendMailAsync(
               new MailMessage(userName, email, subject, htmlMessage) { IsBodyHtml = 
           true }
           );
       }


       public Task SendBulkEmailAsync(string[] emails, string subject, string 
         htmlMessage)
       {
           var client = new SmtpClient(host, port)
           {
               Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password),
               EnableSsl = enableSSL
           };

           MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
           mailMessage.Body = htmlMessage;
           mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
           mailMessage.Subject = subject;

           foreach (string emailAdress in emails)
           {
               if (CheckIsValiedEmailAddress(emailAdress))
                  mailMessage.To.Add(emailAdress);
           }


           return client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage); ;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Finally All instances of 'IEmailSender' replace to 'IExtendedEmailSender'.

Answer (score 2):

The `MailMessage.To` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to?view=netcore-3.0) is of the type [MailAddressCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection?view=netcore-3.0). This means, that you can use the `Add` method to add multiple recipients.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("email1@evilcorp.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("email2@evilcorp.com"));
```

Comment: How to pass MailAddressCollection to SendEmailAsync method?

Comment: You don't. You pass the MailMessage to the SendEmailAsync method

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (email != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.Trim()))
        {
            var lst = new List<string>(
                (email + "").Split(';').Select(tag => tag.Trim()).Where(tag => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag)));
            foreach (var s in lst)
                msg.AddTo(s);
        }
```